# Display page full screen

Tags: html, angular, angular6

I'm writing web-page using angular 6, When I rendered components on the web-page I got the white block(free space block) at the bottom.

When I've tried to view this page with F12 tools, I can't find why this have happened

You can see it on the screen. May be I did something wrong

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/OANS7.jpg

When inspect this empty block got this

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbfop.jpg

How can I fixe this empty block?

## Update

My dashboard.html

```
<div>

 <br>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="container">
      <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="20px" fxLayout.gt-md="row"  fxLayoutAlign="space-around center" class="content">
          <div class="blocks">
              <button button="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary">
                  <mat-icon>add</mat-icon> Add Filter
              </button>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" class="content">
    <mat-card class="card" >
      <mat-card-title fxLayout.gt-xs="row" fxLayout.xs="column">
        <h3>Recent Posts</h3>
      </mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-content>
          <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
              <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

                <ng-container matColumnDef="data_posted">
                  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Date </mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.date_posted | date: 'd/M/y'  }} </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
                  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Title </mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.title}} </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="category">
                  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Category </mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.category}} </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></mat-header-row>
                <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
              </mat-table>
            </div>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Arbitration</title>
  <base href="/">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add your template file code and css file to be able to know the issue

Comment: @KenanaReda I don't know what code should I add? I said, that I don't know why this empty block is there

Comment: plz add  .html file

Comment: @KenanaReda I've added

Comment: is the CSS height set on HTML and body to 100%? is there a margin somewhere forcing it? this seems like it is a CSS issue so you might want to add that tag and include any relevant CSS.

Comment: You can use Inspect Element to determine where the extras space is coming from.

Comment: @JasonWhite definitely, but when I tried to inspect I got this result https://imgur.com/a/MAKE9eI

Comment: check from margin and padding and height in css file plz

Comment: @KenanaReda just body has margin 0

Comment: okay so create an example of your code here https://stackblitz.com/ to be able to know the reason

Comment: I loaded this dashboard via angular app.Route.ts. Maybe it depends on this?

Comment: @KenanaReda I posted code there, but can't connect angular material...